# Duplicate Symbol Error when Linking in Xcode: '_CRLF' | XCode 15.0 Beta 8

Tags: ios, xcode, linker, clang, linker-errors

My app was working fine on XCode 14.6 and I was able to install it on my iPad.

For testing the app on my iPad on iOS 17 Beta, I updated both my iPad and XCode 14.6 to XCode 15 Beta 8.

Now when I am trying to install it, I get this error:

```
duplicate symbol '_CRLF' in:
    /Users/mac-0077/Desktop/HBook/eBook/Nov_2023/ebookapp copy/eBook/Third Party/PrinterLibrary/libPrinter_170b.a[arm64][4](ZPLPrinter.o)
    /Users/mac-0077/Desktop/HBook/eBook/Nov_2023/ebookapp copy/eBook/Third Party/PrinterLibrary/libPrinter_170b.a[arm64][3](CPCLPrinter.o)
ld: 1 duplicate symbols
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

If I am installing the app using XCode 14.6 on the simulator(iOS 16), it's working.

If I am installing the app using XCode 15.0 beta 8 on the iPad(iOS 17 Beta), it's not working giving the above error.

I have tried many things but nothing worked.

Any help or guidance provided would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for taking the time to assist me!

Tried cleaning build folder, pod disintegration. Nothing worked.

Comment: Please provide more information so the problem can be reproduced. As of now, the problem can only be produced on your machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/731090
Build Setting Other Linker Flags  add "-ld64"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks a lot @xiaoy li! wasted lot of time on this after installing Xcode 15.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a #include ****.cpp in your main.cpp, that might produce the error